# Can I use different memory slots if 1 bank is broken?

Tags: memory

I want to know if I am doing any harm, or LOSING OUT ON PERFORMANCE with my current memory setup.

I have 6 memory slots on my Mobo.
the centre 2 slots are not working and crashes regularly with memory in either of the centre 2 slots.
the 4 outer slots work fine and computer 'seems' stable.
   [tested with memtest86+, AIDA64, Intel Burn Test)

- The owners manual requires the 2nd Stick of ram in the centre bank (slot 3), But I cant do this as its broken.

This is the only option I can think of without having to buy a new Mobo.

- i tried cleaning & repairing the centre banks; took ages, but no luck.

Am I going to run into problems or have performance issues ?
Will I still get dual channel and same frequency and speed performance (ram) ?

Mobo:   GA-X58A-UD3R_v2
Ram:  DDR3 Kingston Hyper 1600 2GB (x4)

Thank you  ;)

[photo of memory banks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI0GH.jpg)

[Motherboard Manual - Memory Slot Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51hLI.jpg)

Comment: I don't really see a problem with skipping slots 3 and 4, you will be limited to dual channel vs triple channel if you had 6 sticks, but that shouldn't be a big deal.  The bigger issue is that slots 3 and 4 don't work in the first place.  If its really the DIMM slots that are the issue, and not the ram that was in them, that indicates a potentially serious issue with the motherboard.  I doubt I would expect it to last very long, hopefully if it dies it doesn't take anything else with it.

Comment: Really?  I didnt realize that this could be a sign of worse things to come. If motherboard decides to die, could it break the CPU or Graphics card or other things ?  I can only imagine a voltage surge would do that.  ps: the problem is definitely the middle Memory Bank (and not the memory itself).